# jQuery Cycle Plugin curtainX first animation messed up

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Ok so I got the curtainX working properly on my images, but just on the first initial load, the image shrinks up and disappears at the top and then loads the other image and THEN it finally does the curtainX image.. is there a reason that the first animation is not even related to the curtainX effect?

```
        jQuery('.product_show').cycle({
            fx: 'curtainX',
            sync: false,
            speed: 1300,
            timeout: 2000,
            delay: 1000
        });
```

Here's the homepage of the plugin : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
It's in the second row in the middle.. it's suppose to look just like that, but it does a weird animation for JUST the first animation and then it works awesome the rest of the time.

Here is the video of my site since it's on my local machine : http://s1284.photobucket.com/user/IntellectProductions/media/LivestreamforProducers-20130912-131736_446_zpsd84e6c90.mp4.html You can see what the animation is diong based off that code I posted.

And I even created an example with NO CSS so we know no CSS is getting into the way and the curtainX still does it:
http://intellectproductions.com/test/html.html

I really need this to work since I need the flip effect on my images.

Comment: Any chance we can see the "weird animation"?!

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how to record my screen and put it here though..

Comment: It's for a website I can't release information about so I can't give you the direct URL because it's on my local machine.

Comment: Posted a video of the animation it is doing @A. Wolff

Comment: Could be a CSS rule not setted correctly the first time but without all relevant code or better test case it's quite impossible to help more. I don't think your issue comes from jquery code you have posted

Comment: I literally erased all my CSS on the div surrounding the images and the actual image tags and it still does it.

Comment: No @A. Wolff, it's not CSS : http://intellectproductions.com/test/html.html I just did pure jquery of JUST the cycle plugin along with a set of images and it even does it there. I have NO CSS. Zippo.

Comment: On the first cycle, the height for the first image is not setted, you need to use CSS rule height:450px; for first image or in jquery: `$('.product_block img:first').height(450);` or set it with attribute height="450". Test and see...

Comment: Genius! But why 450? I can't have a defined height though since as you see for the final example, it's a stacked grid that needs to remain responsive so the height needs to be set as "auto"

Comment: Thank you so much!! I figured it out! :D

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @A. Wolff, this was the solution since it needed to maintain it's responsiveness and the height couldn't be hard-coded.

```
    jQuery('.product_block .product_show').each(function() {

        imgHeight = jQuery(this).children(':first').height();
        jQuery(this).children(':first').height(imgHeight);

        val = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        val = val.split(' ');
        //timeout_time = val.substr(val.indexOf('-') + 1);
        timeout_time = val[1].substr(8);

        jQuery(this).cycle({
            fx: 'curtainX',
            sync: false,
            speed: 1300,
            timeout: timeout_time,
            delay: 1000
        });

        turn = turn - 3000;
    });
```

Please take note as setting the height here:

```
imgHeight = jQuery(this).children(':first').height();
jQuery(this).children(':first').height(imgHeight);
```